# shebang changed to /usr/libexec/platform-python when building python rpm packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpmbuild

I am trying to build a  RPM from a python application on RHEL8.2 machine.

the shebangs on the scripts are set correctly to `#!/usr/bin/python3`
however for some reason the shebang gets changed to `#!/usr/libexec/platform-python -s` when the RPM is built.

I have tried almost everything.

I have undefined the mangling according to doc: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/packaging_and_distributing_software/advanced-topics

```
 %undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs
```

but the shebangs gets still changed.

this is the relevant parts of the specs file:

```
%undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs
Name: myapp
Version: 2.0.0
Release: 1%{?dist}
summary: rpm for my APP

BuildArch: noarch

### Build Dependencies ###
BuildRequires: python3-setuptools
BuildRequires: python3-devel

%?python_enable_dependency_generator

%build
%py3_build


%install
%py3_install

%files
....
```

I can include `python*-rpm-macros` to the specs and that would set the shebang to something like `/usr/bin/python3.6` but it is  too restrictive. Our code works in anything > python3.6 so if we deploy the rpm in a system with python3.8 it should work.

how can I set /usr/bin/python3 or leave the shebang unchanged on the python scripts? when the rpm is packaged?

Answer (score 1):

`%undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs` works for me.

```
$ rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.14.3
```

Perhaps you need to put it later in your preamble? eg:

```
Name: myapp
Version: 2.0.0
Release: 1%{?dist}
summary: rpm for my APP

BuildArch: noarch

### Build Dependencies ###
BuildRequires: python3-setuptools
BuildRequires: python3-devel

## Fixes
# disable shebang mangling of python scripts
%undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs

...
```

Note also there seem to be some additional variables that give finer grained control, however I have not tried these:

Excluding based on shebang:

```
%global __mangle_shebangs_exclude ruby
```

Excluding based on path:

```
%global __mangle_shebangs_exclude_from /test/
```

Reference: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/redhat-rpm-config/pull-request/19

I would also note that the document cited above is incorrect: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/packaging_and_distributing_software/advanced-topics section 4.6.2

> To prevent the BRP script from checking and modifying interpreter
> directives, use the following RPM directive:
>
> %undefine %brp_mangle_shebangs

as it is `%undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs`

Comment: Good answer. Note that, according to https://bugzilla.redhat.comw/show_bug.cgi?id=1597664, `%define __brp_mangle_shebangs %{nil}` is more robust against RPM configuration oddities.